# presentViewController changes the orientation of the controller

Tags: ios, screen-orientation

I want to play a video from a view controller. When I present it, it is presented like it is a portrait orientation, so view turns. It only happens on iPhones,not the iPads.

There is a ViewController > MyItemsController > VideoController

[image]

When I close the VideoController, parent controller (MyItemsController) of the video controller is like:

[image]

Storyboard of the view controller is:

[image]

And the code is:

```
-(void)playMoviesForItems:(NSArray *)shopItems{
    VideoPlayerViewController* moviePlayer = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"videoPlayerController"];
    moviePlayer.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    moviePlayer.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:moviePlayer animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

I moved the code into app delegate :

```
-(void)playMoviesForItems:(NSArray *)shopItems{
VideoPlayerViewController* mp = [[self getStoryboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"videoPlayerController"];
[mp playMoviesForItems:shopItems];
[self pauseBackgroundMusic];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:mp animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

This time, everything seem to be ok. Movie is playing, I can hear the sound, but cannot see the video. Why?
[image]

Comment: Do you want to lock the app in a specific orientation?

Comment: I normally locked it Landscape mode. But this controller presented like that in iPhone. iPad is normal.

Comment: Have you fixed this? I have the same problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the accepted answer was down voted since it does not answer the question, here's something that works on iOS9 :

The method that gets called when the ViewController is presented (modally) is `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation`. This method must return an orientation.
You should check the presenter's orientation and return it as preferred:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
        UIInterfaceOrientation topOrientation = self.navigationController.visibleViewController.interfaceOrientation;
        UIInterfaceOrientation presentingOrientation = self.presentingViewController.interfaceOrientation;

        return   presentingOrientation ? presentingOrientation : topOrientation ? topOrientation : UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

`topOrientation` contains the visible view controller's orientation, while the `presentingOrientation` is the orientation of the called to `presentViewController:animated...`
In general, I advise you to create a "base" UIViewController class, and inherit from it. This way all of your view controllers will benefit from this code.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exactly same problem a few minutes ago.

What happened to me is that I was trying to present the new `ViewController` with a another `ViewController` which wasn't in the hierarchy, it only had it's view added as a `subview` of a third `ViewController` in the hierarchy. To fix the problem, I just made this last `ViewController` present the new one.

Example of what not to do:

```
UIViewController *secondController = [UIViewController alloc] init];
[rootViewController presentViewController:secondController animated:NO completion:nil];

UIViewController *controllerOutsideHierarchy = [UIViewController alloc] init];
[secondController.view addSubview:controllerOutsideHierarchy.view];

[controllerOutsideHierarchy presentViewController:thirdController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Example of what should be done instead:

```
UIViewController *secondController = [UIViewController alloc] init];
[rootViewController presentViewController:secondController animated:NO completion:nil];

UIViewController *controllerOutsideHierarchy = [UIViewController alloc] init];
[secondController.view addSubview:controllerOutsideHierarchy.view];

[secondController presentViewController:thirdController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.1 version**

To prevent auto rotation orientation you need to override `shouldAutorotate` variable

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}
```

To present view controller in landscape mode you need to override `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` variable

```
override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return .landscapeLeft// or .landscapeRight
}
```

You need to present view controller to get it work(It doesn't work for pushed view controller)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add these two in the *child* view controller:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}
```

Comment: And `application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` in `AppDelegate`?

Comment: I added - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)w {
    
    return (NSUInteger)[application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:w] | (1<<UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape);
    
} but it doesn work.

Comment: You need to `return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;`, nothing else. Also, note, this value is already a mask, you don't need to `1 <<` it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape);
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape);
}
```

Try this...

Comment: I don't like the way people posting code without any explanation

Answer (score 0):

you must add the methods below , in your self.window.rootViewController 'class:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}


@end
```

if your rootViewController is [UINavigationController class], command+n add a category of UINavigationController ,like my code below

```
@implementation UINavigationController (Rotation_For_iOS6)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}


@end
```

and then ,go to the viewController.m which u want to be landscape or portrait mode,maybe for u is your VideoController !!!!!! 
add methods below:

```
#pragma mark
#pragma mark ----- Orientation Control For iOS 6/7 -----

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight||toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

now i set my vc supported for landscape mode, last but not least,make sure your project deployment info select the orientation your want.